# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.show()'

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an exception on Crashlytics that doesn't show any of my code on the stack trace, how can I figure out what is causing it? Seems to be happening exclusively on Android 5.0 and 5.0.1. I am using the support library 23.4.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.show()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Editor$SelectionActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(Editor.java:3023)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3163)
       at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:155)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onCreateActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1742)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.startSupportActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:696)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.startAsSupportActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:187)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14$AppCompatWindowCallbackV14.onWindowStartingActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:171)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:145)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2644)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2631)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:694)
       at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4857)
       at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1626)
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:914)
       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8900)
       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19735)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

EDIT1: A user who reported the crash figured out how to reproduce it. It happens when he uses my `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` to select all the text and copy it to the clipboard. It only happens on Android 5.0 and 5.0.1

EDIT2: I think it is happening on more than just Android 5 but the stacktrace looks different enough that Crashlytics doesn't group it. Based on some posts I found I think it has to do with the Contextual Actionbar height or how it calculates it but I haven't found a clear answer yet.

Comment: What code? Did you read the question? *that doesn't show any of my code on the stack* ... error seems to come on text selecting with long click in compat EditView(when system shows copy/paste/etc. options) and looks like a bug in support lib

Comment: @Vucko like Selvin said, my code is nowhere on the stack trace so I have no idea what to post or where to start looking. Everyone of my activities uses the app compat activity, but I'm not even sure if that is where the issue is. I don't understand the downvotes, someone please explain.

Comment: @GabeSechan but which code? my code isn't anywhere on the stack trace.

Comment: I'd guess anything with action modes.  Since that seems to be where the failure occurs.  Particularly code with setting them up

Comment: @GabeSechan a user figured out how to reproduce it. Happens when he copies text out of my `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: Figured it out, it was an issue with long pressing on an `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` that changes when focus changes.

Comment: same issue happened with me for Samsung lollipop devices..for me it was because of long press and showing keyboard at the same time..I could resolve by putting a timer for long click..and handling showing keyboard accordingly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` that changes size when it is on focus. Turns out users were long pressing on it while it was on the collapsed size and when the `onFocusChange` event fired the whole thing would change and it would crash.

Answer (score 2):

You can reproduce that by calling `setText("test");` inside `onFocusChange` and long pressing that `EditText` on Samsung s8 (I am not sure about other devices).

As a solution you may try to get rid of setting text or other manipulations which causes text rearrangement in onFocusChange or delaying it with handler.