# java.lang.NullPointerException: at android.widget.Editor.updateFloatingToolbarVisibility

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-7.0-nougat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.widget.Editor.updateFloatingToolbarVisibility(Editor.java:1541)
  at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1491)
  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10025)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10723)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:559)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1870)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3236)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:521)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10952)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5117)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4969)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4500)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4519)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4652)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4527)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4709)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4500)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4553)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4519)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4527)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4500)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7007)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6936)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6897)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7117)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method:0)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7081)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7144)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:632)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

This is not a duplicate post.

A user has reported this issue but I don't know how to reproduce it and fix it. It happens in Android N Samsung Device.

My guess is it happens in a EditText.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Any idea about this issue.

Comment: @Rameshbabu Found a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926522/java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-nougat

Comment: @Rameshbabu I was unable to reproduce the issue. Can you help?

Comment: @IronMan right now am trying to reproduce in my samsung s6 device. Have you used Autocomplete text view in your code.

Comment: @Rameshbabu No, I am not using autocomplete. I am trying it my Galaxy Note 5

Comment: @Rameshbabu Any improvement?

Comment: @IronMan i have tried to reproduce this issue. So far no luck.

Comment: Are you able to find any solution?

Comment: If you are using TextInputLayout make sure you have specify hint in both views TextInputLayout and EditText

Answer (score -2):

Null pointer exceptions are almost always because an element hasn't been correctly initialized in the code before an attempt is made to reference it.
E.g. make sure the TextView object exists before trying to use it:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView();
```

Comment: There is no such object. I don't know why it appears in the logs.

Comment: Apparently it's a helper object for the TextView widget class https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/Editor.java. So probably your TextView instance needs to be instantiated before trying to access it.