# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: on S7 mobile

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-7.0-nougat

I am getting below exception when tries long press on Editor control in xamarin.android app. This issue is occurring on Samsung S7 with OS Verison 7.0

> Unhandled Exception:  Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'boolean
>   android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.isDragAcceleratorActive()'
>   on a null object reference occurred

And below is the stack trace for the exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.isDragAcceleratorActive()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.Editor.updateFloatingToolbarVisibility(Editor.java:1520)
    at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java:1475)
    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10024)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10725)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:738)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native Method)
    at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(PlatformRenderer.java:55)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2550)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:505)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1863)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3226)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:467)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10954)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5051)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4908)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4439)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4492)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4458)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4591)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4466)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4648)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4439)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4492)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4458)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4466)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4439)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6936)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6875)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6836)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7046)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7010)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7073)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:632)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

We are creating the Editor control dynamically.

And this issue is not occurring on any other device.

Any help on this appreciated. !

Comment: Do you have any code or custom renderers in place that can cause this? If so, please post it

Comment: @GeraldVersluis We are creating the controls dynamically

Comment: Show us your dynamic code generation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926522/java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-nougat