# App crashes when long clicking on Text view Hint

Tags: java, android, exception

I have a text view in my app and whenever I long click the hint of the Text View the app crashes. I'm not able to figure out why.

**LogCat:**

```
2018-09-25 17:02:39.171 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/ViewRootImpl@2f6e516[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
2018-09-25 17:02:39.174 25737-25737/com.domain.app W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
2018-09-25 17:02:39.175 25737-25737/com.domain.app E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
2018-09-25 17:02:39.175 25737-25737/com.domain.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
2018-09-25 17:02:39.678 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/TextView: performLongClick() is called
2018-09-25 17:02:39.687 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/TextView: handled is false
2018-09-25 17:02:39.745 25737-25737/com.domain.app E/ClipboardServiceEx: clipEx is com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager@fdc3f2f
2018-09-25 17:02:39.859 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
2018-09-25 17:02:39.865 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@6d8cca4
2018-09-25 17:02:39.867 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3814a0d
2018-09-25 17:02:39.867 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@3814a0d
2018-09-25 17:02:39.893 25737-25737/com.domain.app E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2018-09-25 17:02:39.893 25737-25737/com.domain.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
2018-09-25 17:02:39.895 25737-25737/com.domain.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.domain.app, PID: 25737
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.isDragAcceleratorActive()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Editor.updateFloatingToolbarVisibility(Editor.java)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchEvent(Editor.java)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
2018-09-25 17:02:39.895 25737-25737/com.domain.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: just a pure textView?

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah. Turns out it is a samsung specific bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out **this is a samsung specific issue**.

The solution for me was to disable long click on the element `android:longClickable="false"`
 (I can afford to do that).  If you do not want to disable long click for all the devices the you may have to disable only for samsung one's.

Refer this to block long click for only Samsung devices:
[java.lang.NullPointerException with Nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926522/java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-nougat)