# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, google-fabric

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1174)

       at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:12717)

       at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:6954)

       at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:26066)

       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)

       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)

       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)

       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at 
com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)

       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

any one help me about this crash.how I solved this.its reported on fabric again and again.

Comment: can you post some codes as well, where it might have occurred?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978026/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void-android-w.

Comment: @theanilpaudel I do not know where this crash is occurred in code because from fabric report Editor.java show the error and it is built in class of android API.

Comment: @ADM got some idea..

Comment: Are you able to find the solution? I've also a large number of the same exception mentioned in a fabric.

Answer (score 3):

Some devices have thrown me that problem by keeping a long press on them when they do not have the focus

Add listener `OnLongClick` in each editable components of the layout

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        textView.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
});
```